# ASP.NET web control only allow specific contents?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP .NET web controls, but not ASP .NET in general or C#.

I am wondering how I can limit the allowed content types to a specific class.

I have made a custom web control called TabPanel, and I want it to only be able to contain TabPages.

As an example, the following markup should be illegal, since it contains a checkbox.

```
<cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
    <cc1:TabPage runat="server">
        this is a simple test
    </cc1:TabPage>
    <cc1:TabPage runat="server">
        this is another simple test
    </cc1:TabPage>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" />
</cc1:TabPanel>
```

In this case, I wouldn't want the checkbox to be there. How can I block this from happening?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: @John: My assumption is they are writing a custom control, and don't want the container to accept controls of type X (in this case X=CheckBox)

Comment: Maybe you should be a bit more constructive. How does it not make sense?

Comment: I have rephrased the question a bit. Should be more detailed.

Comment: Ok, if you don't want the checkbox to be there, don't put it there. If you're saying you don't want it to be there in certain instances, explain what those are. Is hiding the checkbox enough? or do you want to remove it from the controls collection? You could say TabPanel1.Controls.Remove("idofcheckbox"); for the conditions you want to remove it.

Comment: Ok now it makes sense. So I'm not sure how you could prevent the markup of adding other control types, thanks for rephrasing it. Not sure how you would bind a constraint like that, it would need to be bound to the control somehow that when you compile it produced a compilation error, I don't think it's possible, but I'm not able to say for sure.

Comment: John, we represent a large development firm, not just some playground initiative. We have many developers, and we want to customize what kind of controls this webcontrol should accept, so that we are sure that this is not being violated.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your guess at least.

Comment: Well you question makes more sense now. Sorry I'm unable to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Had to throw an exception under AddedControl procedure that I overrided from the WebControl if the type of the control being added was not of the type I wanted.

Now the designer shows a beautiful red error-message on the control itself, preventing me from doing such a foolish thing.

Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried exactly what you are after but based on other things I have done I would try this:

- Create a property in TabPannel that is a collection of TabPages (call it Tabs for demonstration purposes).  This can be an array, a list, or a custom collection class, the key is to have typed to only accept TabPages as members.
- Give the property the [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)] atribute.
- Override CreateChildControls to add the contents of the collection to the control.

If you do it this way then your mark up should end up looking something like this:

```
<cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
    <Tabs>
        <cc1:TabPage runat="server">this is a simple test</cc1:TabPage>
        <cc1:TabPage runat="server">this is another simple test</cc1:TabPage>
    </Tabs>
</cc1:TabPanel>
```

and it should not allow anything that is not a TabPage to be nested inside of the Tabs property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x(v=VS.90).aspx is a walk through demonstrating this technique in detail.

Comment: Interesting indeed. I ended up going by my own answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess here, but based on some [quick googling](http://forums.asp.net/t/1467317.aspx/1) I think you're looking for the [ControlBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilder.aspx). The demo limits their control to an object called "mycell", but I don't see any reason why this couldn't be limited to your own objects, or build-in ASP.NET controls (i.e. Panels but not TextBoxes, etc.)

As a last resort, I'm sure you could hijack the rendering method and only render controls within the pre-determined class set, but this seems hack-ish at best.